# clopen sets of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I would like to ask a question about clopen (a subset is both open and closed) subsets of a topological space.  Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Denote with $\tau_{clop}$ the all clopen subsets of the space. If only the open subsets of the space is clopen then $\tau=\tau_{clop}$. Is there any specific name of this type of topological spaces?

Comment: If you assume $T_1$ property then the only such spaces are discrete spaces.

Comment: Yes indeed, I just wondered the general specific name of this type of spaces without assuming it is $T_{1]$. Thank you. @geetha290krm

Comment: These are called "partition spaces", since (equivalently) they have a base, which is a partition of the space, or equivalently, they are Alexandroff (i.e. each point is contained in  a minimal open set) and T3.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will see it. @Ulli